# How to avoid Vim error message "Not an editor command"

Tags: vim

Let's say I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
au bufenter * RainbowParenthesesToggle
```

However I'm on a unfamiliar machine and I haven't installed all of my plugins yet. This means when I start up Vim I get this error message:

```
E492: Not an editor command: RainbowParenthesesToggle
```

How can I guard against this, or what if statement do I want to wrap these calls in to avoid getting this error message when I start Vim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### suppress

The easiest would be to just suppress the error message via `:silent!` (note the `!`):

```
:au bufenter * silent! RainbowParenthesesToggle
```

#### check each time

It's cleaner (especially for an autocmd that runs on each `BufEnter`) to avoid the call. The existence of a command can be checked with `exists(':RainbowParenthesesToggle') == 2`.

```
:au bufenter * if exists(':RainbowParenthesesToggle') == 2 | RainbowParenthesesToggle | endif
```

#### avoid definition

It would be best to check only once, and avoid defining the autocmd at all. The problem is that your `~/.vimrc` is *sourced before the plugins*! There are two ways around this:

1) Explicitly source the plugin before the check:

```
runtime! plugin/rainbowparentheses.vim
if exists(':RainbowParenthesesToggle') == 2
    au bufenter * RainbowParenthesesToggle
endif
```

2) Move the definition and conditional to a location that is sourced *after* the plugins. `~/.vim/after/plugin/rainbowparentheses.vim` would be a good place for this.

Comment: Also how would advice 3 - source the plugin first - change if I was using pathogen?

Comment: That stands for "exact match", see `:help exists()`.

Comment: Pathogen extends the `'runtimepath'`, which `:runtime` uses. Should work the same, as long as the Pathogen stuff comes first.

Comment: When I copy the code here: `:au bufenter * if exists(':RainbowParenthesesToggle') == 2 | RainbowParenthesesToggle | endif` I get an error `Trailing characters: RainbowParenthesesToggle | endif`

Comment: Oh, the command cannot be directly put into a command sequence. Use `exe 'RainbowParenthesesToggle'` instead of `RainbowParenthesesToggle`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the command using `exists()`:

```
au bufenter * if exists(":RainbowParenthesesToggle") | RainbowParenthesesToggle | endif
```

(I have no such command defined myself, so I can verify that this works. :) )